# Saber si una API me devuelve una respuesta con código de estado 200

Tags: javascript, api, test, jest, jestjs

Básicamente estoy empezando con Jest y estoy queriendo saber con esta herramienta si una API me devuelve una respuesta con código de estado 200. He buscado muchas maneras de hacerlo en internet pero ninguna me resultó efectiva y no dejan de saltarme errores, además de que directamente no sé cómo armar dicho pedido que mencioné y sinceramente me tiene demasiado frustrado.

¿Alguno me podría dar una mano con respecto a eso?

Por ejemplo, hacer un llamado a la API de Rick & Morty ya sea con Axios o Fetch y ver si devuelve un código de estado 200:

https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character

Intenté algo como esto:

Archivo "mock.js"

```
import axios from "axios";

class Movies {
    static all() {
        return axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character').then(resp => resp.data);
    }
}

export default Movies;
```

Archivo "mock.test.js":

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Movies from './mock.js';

jest.mock('axios');

test('should return a 200 status code', () => {
    expect(Movies.status).toBe(200)
})
```

Y me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: Result]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so] recuerda realizar el [tour] y revisar [ask]. Puedes comenzar por agregar a tu pregunta cada una de las opciones que has intentado y que no te han funcionado

Comment: ¿Y el código que has realizado? lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: ¿Estás haciendo pruebas unitarias?

Comment: @fredyfx Sí, algo parecido, soy bastante nuevo en el tema del testing, lo siento.

Comment: `Intenté algo como esto: <pones código de pruebas unitarias>` Tu pregunta está enredada, edita paso a paso, de preferencia siguiendo las recomendaciones del enlace que te dejé previamente. Relax, nadie nació sabiendo, todos vamos aprendiendo. :)

Comment: @fredyfx Claro, básicamente solo quiero saber si esa API me está devolviendo un status code de 200, nada más. El problema está en que ni siquiera se muy bien cómo pedirlo, por más que lea y lo intente.

Comment: En pruebas unitarias, se hace un Mock de la llamada al server. Palabras clave: `javascript jest unit testing mock http service`.

Comment: @fredyfx Hola de nuevo :) ahí modifiqué la pregunta otra vez, esta vez volví a empezar desde cero y llegué hasta ese punto, y ahí ya me estanqué.